# WPF Animation StoryBoard SpeedRatio changing but not having effect

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, if-statement, storyboard

many thanks in advance.

I came across a bizarre behaviour. I have the method below, that is called correctly, no problems found. AnimationRunning is a boolean that evaluates correctly to true, but the actual speed of the animation remains the same, even when the value stored in the SpeedRatio is changed (as made evident by the statusbar label), the actual animation speed remains the same.

```
 private void TextBoxTyping(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AnimationRunning == true) { StoryBoard.SpeedRatio += 5; }; 
        statusbar.Content = "Speed: " + StoryBoard.SpeedRatio.ToString();
    }
```

To check whether the AnimationRunning evaluates to true, I popped in a **MessageBox.Show("Animation is running");** inside the if closure. And the message does pop out.

However, if I change the code to the following:

```
 private void TextBoxTyping(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        StoryBoard.SpeedRatio += 5; 
        statusbar.Content = "Speed: " + StoryBoard.SpeedRatio.ToString();
    }
```

The speed of the animation does change.
I can't get my head around on how with AnimationRunning being true, I can't get the SpeedRatio to work inside the if statement...

Could help shine some light in this poor mind of mine?
Thanks...

Comment: The StoryBoard exists inside the public partial class MainWindow : Window

Comment: Not sure I _can't modify_ entirely. I can change the speed of the animation while it's running, if I apply the speed change outside the if-statement.

Comment: Speed != timeline, my bad. I'd recommend you to write [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are big chances you discover the problem yourself (usually when you can't reproduce the issue). If you succeed, post it here, some important detail is missing in your code sample currently.

Answer (score 0):

To Set the interactive speed ratio of the Clock that was created for this Storyboard use [Storyboard.SetSpeedRatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605784(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **From MSDN:** To interactively control this storyboard, you must use the
>   same containingObject parameter when calling the interactive methods
>   that you used to begin the storyboard. A controllable storyboard can
>   pause, resume, seek, stop, and be removed. To make a storyboard
>   controllable in code, you must use the appropriate overload of the
>   storyboard's Begin method and specify true to make it controllable.

Comment: I tried this, still no error, and still no change in the speed of the animation, but now the speed reported on the statusbar label doesn't change. If I use the SpeedRatio instead, the speed is correctly reported.

Comment: Hi, Can you please make sure whether your storyboard is controllable. "To make a storyboard controllable in code, you must use the appropriate overload of the storyboard's Begin method and specify true to make it controllable."